# I am having problems with image upload in php

Tags: php, database, upload

I have this form that takes text input and below it you can upload images ,maximum of four (but its optional ,you can choose not to upload an image ).
Then the text and image or images gets assigned to the currently logged in user in the database .
I have a challenge however , when I use all the available image upload inputs ,it successfully uploads and assigns to the database.
But when I upload less than 4 ,either 1,2,or 3 , nothing happens.Please help check my code below.

```
<?php 
include("ot_includes/session.php");

include ('ot_includes/profile_info_fetcher.php');
include ('ot_includes/header.php'); 

include ('ot_includes/db_connect.php');
include("ot_includes/forum_profile_header.php");




// Begining of news for m processor



$current_time= time();
$last_create_time_diff=($current_time - $get_last_create_time);

if (isset
  ($_POST["submit_topic"]) AND 

  !empty($_POST["topic_title"]) AND 

  !empty($_POST["topic_body"]) AND 

  !empty($_POST["topic_category"] ) 
  AND

  ( $last_create_time_diff > 1800 )


  AND 

  (strlen($_POST["topic_title"]) < 101)
  ) 
{

    $topic_create_time= time();
  $topic_title= $_POST['topic_title'] ;
  $topic_body= $_POST['topic_body'] ;
  $topic_category= $_POST['topic_category'] ;


//upload image 



//   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
//       echo('<script> window.location = "../index.php";</script>');

// }


   if(isset($_FILES['upload_thread_image1'])){
      $errors= array();
      //for first image
      $file_name_1 = $_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['name'];
      $file_size_1 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['size'];
      $file_tmp_1 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type_1=$_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['type'];
      $file_explode_1=explode('.',$_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['name']);
      $file_ext_1=strtolower(end( $file_explode_1));


      //for second image
      $file_name_2 = $_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['name'];
      $file_size_2 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['size'];
      $file_tmp_2 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type_2=$_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['type'];
      $file_explode_2=explode('.',$_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['name']);
      $file_ext_2=strtolower(end( $file_explode_2));


   //for third image
      $file_name_3 = $_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['name'];
      $file_size_3 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['size'];
      $file_tmp_3 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type_3=$_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['type'];
      $file_explode_3=explode('.',$_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['name']);
      $file_ext_3=strtolower(end( $file_explode_3));


        //for fourth image
      $file_name_4 = $_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['name'];
      $file_size_4 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['size'];
      $file_tmp_4 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type_4=$_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['type'];
      $file_explode_4=explode('.',$_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['name']);
      $file_ext_4=strtolower(end( $file_explode_4));




      $current_time=time();
      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if( 

        (in_array($file_ext_1,$expensions) === false) OR  
        (in_array($file_ext_2,$expensions) === false) OR  
        (in_array($file_ext_3,$expensions) === false) OR  
        (in_array($file_ext_4,$expensions) === false)  

       )

      {
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if(
        ($file_size_1 > 2000000 ) OR
        ($file_size_2 > 2000000) OR
        ($file_size_3 > 2000000) OR
        ($file_size_4 > 2000000) 
        ){
         $errors[]='File size must not exceed 2 MB';
      }


      if(empty($errors)==true){
        $current_time=time();
        $file_name_1=$current_time.$get_username.$file_name_1;
        $file_name_2=$current_time.$get_username.$file_name_2;
        $file_name_3=$current_time.$get_username.$file_name_3;
        $file_name_4=$current_time.$get_username.$file_name_4;

         // $file_name=$file_name.$current_time;
         // $insert_profile_pic= mysqli_query($db_connect,"  oton_users SET user_profile_pic='$file_name' WHERE user_name='$user_check' ");


//            echo '




// <br>
// <div class="row" >


// <h2 align="center" class="alert alert-success"><p><i class="fa fa-5x fa-smile-o"></i></p>Your profile picture has been successfully updated !!!<br> Please click <a href="edit_profile.php"> <u> here</u></a> to go back</h2>


// </div>
// <hr>
// ';
//       }


//       else{
//          echo '




// <br>
// <div class="row" >


// <h2 align="center" class="alert alert-danger"><p><i class="fa fa-5x fa-frown-o"></i></p>Sorry there was an error updating your profile picture<br>Please make sure its less than 2MB and its either jpg,jpeg,or png format<br> Please click <a href="edit_profile.php"> <u> here</u></a> to go back</h2>


// </div>
// <hr>
// ';
//       }




move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_1,"ot_imgs/ot_thread_imgs/".$file_name_1);

  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_2,"ot_imgs/ot_thread_imgs/".$file_name_2);  
  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_3,"ot_imgs/ot_thread_imgs/".$file_name_3);
  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_4,"ot_imgs/ot_thread_imgs/".$file_name_4);





if (empty($file_name_1) OR empty($file_name_2) or empty($file_name_3) or empty($file_name_4) ) {


$file_name_1=" " ;
$file_name_2=" " ;
$file_name_3=" " ;
$file_name_4=" " ;
}


  $insert_topic= "INSERT INTO oton_topics (topic_title,topic_body,topic_category,topic_create_time,topic_by,topic_image_1,topic_image_2,topic_image_3,topic_image_4) VALUES ('$topic_title','$topic_body','$topic_category','$topic_create_time','$get_username','$file_name_1','$file_name_2','$file_name_3','$file_name_4')";
  $topic_result=mysqli_query($db_connect,$insert_topic);

  $update_last_create_time=mysqli_query($db_connect,"UPDATE oton_users SET user_last_create_time='$topic_create_time' WHERE user_id='$get_user_id' ");




if ($topic_result AND $update_last_create_time ) {

    $topic_report= '<div class="alert alert-success" align="center"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-check-circle"></i> Your topic has been posted !!.View your posts  <a href ="view_thread.php?latest_post=1 "><u>here</u></a> </div>';




 } 

  } //from image conditions
}//from image conditions


}



elseif (isset
  ($_POST["submit_topic"]) OR 

  ($_POST["topic_title"] == " ") OR 

  ($_POST["topic_body"] == " ") OR 

  ($_POST["topic_category"] ==" ") 
  AND 

  ( $last_create_time_diff < 1800 )


  AND !$topic_result
  ) 
{


   $topic_report="<div class='alert alert-danger'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-warning'></i> There was an error,check the following<br>-Make sure no field is empty.<br>-You have to wait for 30 minutes from the last time you posted<br>-Make sure your title is less than or equal to 100 characters including spaces<br>-Kindly close this tab completely and create a topic in a new tab</div>";

}

//End of news form processor

unset($_POST);


?>


<!--Begin welcome section -->
 <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">
                <h2>Hello <?php echo "$get_username";  ?>!</h2>
                <p>What would you like to do at the moment ?</p>

                <?php echo "$quick_links";  ?>



            </div>


           </div>
           </section>

<hr>




<section class="container">

<?php echo $topic_report ;?>

<h1 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus"></i> Add New Topic</h1><br>


  <form  method="POST" action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<br>
<div class="row" >


<div class='col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 '>


            <div class='form-group'>



      <label>Title</label>

<input class="form-control" align="center" type="text" name="topic_title" />
<br>

      <label>Category</label>
<select class="form-control" name="topic_category">
                      <option value=" ">Select...</option>
                      <option value="sports">Sports</option>
                      <option value="another">another</option>
                      <option value="another2">another2</option>
                      <option value="another3">another3</option>



                      </select> 

<label>Body</label>
<textarea id="tinymyceArea" class="form-control" type="text" name="topic_body" ></textarea>


<br>
<input type="file" name="upload_thread_image1" class="btn btn-danger" />
<input type="file" name="upload_thread_image2" class="btn btn-danger" />
<input type="file" name="upload_thread_image3" class="btn btn-danger" />
<input type="file" name="upload_thread_image4" class="btn btn-danger" />
<br>

<input class="form-control btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit" name="submit_topic" value="Post Topic" />
   <br>



   </div>
        </div>
</div>


</form>

</section>




<?php include ('ot_includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code you want us to debug for you.  Be more specific about "nothing happens".  Surely *something* happens.  What?  Is there an error?  Unexpected results?  Did you check the PHP error logs?  Turn on error reporting on the page?  Check your database queries for errors?  When *you* debug this, where specifically is it failing?

Comment: @David Its a lot of code, but the error is so simple to find, no need to be more specific here. You check: `if(isset($_FILES['upload_thread_image1'])){` and then you assign all the values for image1, 2, 3 and 4. Simply check before every image if it has been posted. Also the move upload file part... check with a `if` condition if the images has been posted or not... if not, don't execute the `move_upload_file` .. right now you're trying to upload files that doesn't exist, what will result in an error.

Comment: @Twinfriends Thanks your solution worked !. I separated each file upload and move_upload_file directly under each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone I have resolved it ,for the sake of anyone that might have a similar problem here is the code that handles the upload.

```
   if(isset($_FILES['upload_thread_image1'])){
      $errors= array();
      //for first image
      $file_name_1 = $_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['name'];
      $file_size_1 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['size'];
      $file_tmp_1 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type_1=$_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['type'];
      $file_explode_1=explode('.',$_FILES['upload_thread_image1']['name']);
      $file_ext_1=strtolower(end( $file_explode_1));




      $current_time=time();
      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if( 

        (in_array($file_ext_1,$expensions) === false)

       )

      {
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if(
        $file_size_1 > 2000000 

        ){
         $errors[]='File size must not exceed 2 MB';
      }


      if(empty($errors)==true){
        $current_time=time();
        $file_name_1=$current_time.$get_username.$file_name_1;

}



move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_1,"ot_imgs/ot_thread_imgs/".$file_name_1);
}






if(isset($_FILES['upload_thread_image2'])){
      $errors= array();
      //for second image
      $file_name_2 = $_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['name'];
      $file_size_2 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['size'];
      $file_tmp_2 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type_2=$_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['type'];
      $file_explode_2=explode('.',$_FILES['upload_thread_image2']['name']);
      $file_ext_2=strtolower(end( $file_explode_2));





      $current_time=time();
      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if( 

        (in_array($file_ext_2,$expensions) === false)

       )

      {
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if(
        $file_size_2 > 2000000 

        ){
         $errors[]='File size must not exceed 2 MB';
      }


      if(empty($errors)==true){
        $current_time=time();
        $file_name_2=$current_time.$get_username.$file_name_2;




      }



      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_2,"ot_imgs/ot_thread_imgs/".$file_name_2);
 }//End for image 2





 if(isset($_FILES['upload_thread_image3'])){
      $errors= array();

   //for third image
      $file_name_3 = $_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['name'];
      $file_size_3 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['size'];
      $file_tmp_3 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type_3=$_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['type'];
      $file_explode_3=explode('.',$_FILES['upload_thread_image3']['name']);
      $file_ext_3=strtolower(end( $file_explode_3));









      $current_time=time();
      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if( 

        (in_array($file_ext_3,$expensions) === false)

       )

      {
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if(
        $file_size_3 > 2000000 

        ){
         $errors[]='File size must not exceed 2 MB';
      }


      if(empty($errors)==true){
        $current_time=time();
        $file_name_3=$current_time.$get_username.$file_name_3;
 }

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_3,"ot_imgs/ot_thread_imgs/".$file_name_3);

}//End for Image 3


if(isset($_FILES['upload_thread_image4'])){
      $errors= array();

        //for fourth image
      $file_name_4 = $_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['name'];
      $file_size_4 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['size'];
      $file_tmp_4 =$_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type_4=$_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['type'];
      $file_explode_4=explode('.',$_FILES['upload_thread_image4']['name']);
      $file_ext_4=strtolower(end( $file_explode_4));






$current_time=time();
      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if( 

        (in_array($file_ext_4,$expensions) === false)

       )

      {
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if(
        $file_size_4 > 2000000 

        ){
         $errors[]='File size must not exceed 2 MB';
      }


      if(empty($errors)==true){
        $current_time=time();
        $file_name_4=$current_time.$get_username.$file_name_4;
       }

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_4,"ot_imgs/ot_thread_imgs/".$file_name_4);

}//end for image 4
```

Then i just input each image variable into the database as required that is $file_name_1,$file_name_2.......

Answer (score 0):

When you check if file name is empty, if file_name_2 is empty then you are renaming all the files to " "(empty)

```
if (empty($file_name_1) OR empty($file_name_2) or empty($file_name_3) or empty($file_name_4) ) {
    $file_name_1=" " ;
    $file_name_2=" " ;
    $file_name_3=" " ;
    $file_name_4=" " ;
}
```

You should individually check if name is empty and rename only those file names.

```
if (empty($file_name_1)) $file_name_1=" " ;
if (empty($file_name_2)) $file_name_2=" " ;
if (empty($file_name_3)) $file_name_3=" " ;
if (empty($file_name_4)) $file_name_4=" " ;
```